# Find version of apt-mirror

Tags: apt-mirror

In several posts I read about issues of specific versions of apt-mirror.

How do I find out the version? I did not see anything in the man page and it has not command line options, also no --help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
apt show apt-mirror
```

Output on my system:

```
qwerty@qwerty-Inspiron-3520:~$ apt show apt-mirror
Package: apt-mirror
Version: 0.5.3-1
Priority: optional
Section: universe/net
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Brandon Holtsclaw <me@brandonholtsclaw.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 65.5 kB
Depends: adduser, wget, perl:any
Homepage: http://apt-mirror.github.com/
Download-Size: 14.1 kB
APT-Sources: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 Packages
Description: APT sources mirroring tool
 A small and efficient tool that lets you mirror a part of or
 the whole Debian GNU/Linux distribution or any other apt sources.
 .
 Main features:
  * It uses a config similar to apts <sources.list>
  * It's fully pool comply
  * It supports multithreaded downloading
  * It supports multiple architectures at the same time
  * It can automatically remove unneeded files
  * It works well on overloaded channel to internet
  * It never produces an inconsistent mirror including while mirroring
  * It works on all POSIX compliant systems with perl and wget
```